# AGO for physical distance?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, adverbs, adverb-position

I have come up with this sentence "I crossed the border 3 kilometers ago". I feel like ago is not the correct adverb since it's used in time contexts. Can you help me find the correct adverb? 
Thank you.

Comment: It's fine as it is, but you can also use *back*.

Answer (score 2):

**Ago** works well here. It retains some of the nuance of time and can only really be replaced by "earlier" - which would refer to **earlier in my journey** which is neutral as to whether it means "at an earlier point", or "at an earlier time."